# Source of qt5 cmake Config-file Packages

Tags: qt, cmake

Trying to build qt5 with buildroot. I need to download the source so that everything is compiled through the cross-compiler.

One of my project relies on the 'Config-file Packages' (CMake helper config file) provided by Qt5 in the binary tarball at this location `Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake`.

Problem: I can't find that folder anywhere in the source. When I take one example file  (e.g. `Qt5Config.cmake`), I can't find any git repo hosting it.
Had a look at Ubuntu packages and it is being distributed in `qtbase5-dev`. When I look at this package [documentation](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/qtbase5-dev), it says it is using `qtbase-opensource-src 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.4` as the source package. Had a look at the [source package for 5.8](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/submodules/qtbase-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz) but the cmake files are not there.

I could upload those files in an ad-hoc git repo, but that just seems weird that those files are not hosted by the qt repo.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmake files are generated while build. On Linux the results are installed to qt/lib/cmake.